# Crete new file in root from admin in php?

Tags: php, fopen, fread

Hi i am reading a file in php from folder admin  filename is createfile.php

and thencreating new file  its working fine but when i crete new file its create in same folder admin  please help to to soleve this problem  how can i crete file out side folder or in root place.

File structure

```
 Admin--
                     |
                     |--createpage.php
```

**Coode here:**

**creatpage.php**

```
 $filename="demo";
$fs=fopen("createfile.php", "r");
$ft=fopen("$filename", "w");
if ($fs==NULL)
{
    echo "Can't Open Source File ...";
    exit(0);
}

if ($ft==NULL)
{
    echo "Can't Open Destination File ...";
    fclose ($fs);
    exit(1);
}

else
{
    while ($ch=fgets($fs))
        fputs($ft, $ch);

    fclose ($fs);
    fclose ($ft);
}
```

Please any one can help me    Thanks

Comment: Just use the path you like: `$ft=fopen("/some/path/to/your/file/$filename", "w");` Note that the target folder must exist (or you have to create it) and you obviously need write permission in the target folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new file in your root path like the below:

```
$rootUrl = "your root url here";
$fs=fopen($rootUrl."createfile.php", "w");
```

Or if you want to create the file just outside Admin directory, you can use "../" like:

```
$fs=fopen("../createfile.php", "w");
```